# What shader do I use to have a shadeless cartoony look on my model?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, uv

Can anyone recommend shaders / materials to use so my model looks something like this? I need it to look like this in Unity as well.

[image]

I want the game to look something cartoony and "shadeless". Here's another sample reference

[image]

Does a shader / material like this exists?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The typical setup for a toon shader is as follows:

[image: Toon1]

Although, your image does seem to have *SOME* shading, so maybe something more like this?

[image: Toon2]

Comment: As far as I'm told, the "shading" was airbrushed in the textures. Is Diffuse BSDF better than Emission if I want my model not to be affected by the scene's lighting?

Comment: Oh, then just plug your image texture directly into the Material output (no shader in between) if you want the material to be unaffected by scene lights

Comment: tried it. but why does the render in the viewport look paler than the original texture?

Comment: Make sure you have your MixRGB node set to "multiply" and not "mix".